# yii2 project create dummy

Tags: php, session, yii2

I have a yii2 project on my PC and I copied it to make a dummy just for development purposes and also I created a new database for that dummy.

My question is that, when I am logged in to the original project and I then access the dummy, it shows that I had already been logged in and the account from the original project displays and vice-versa.

When I first log in to the dummy and then access the original project, it shows that I have already logged in and the dummy login account will display.

How can I have a separate log-in for both sites so that I can be logged in to one site and not the other with the same account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have got the same cookie identity set in both projects. Change it for one of them.

```
'user' => [
    // ...
    'identityCookie' => [
        'name' => '_identity-dummy', // set it here to whatever you like
        'httpOnly' => true
    ],
],
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. on what file i can change it?

Comment: Depends on your project, might be `frontend/config/main.php` or similar.

Comment: i'm using yii2-starter-kit and i can only see identityCookie on vendor